# Should I have intel-microcode installed if my UEFI/BIOS is regularly updated (new machine)?

Tags: linux, security, performance, intel, stability

Hardware: Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577, model number 7577-92774 (new machine).

System: I am testing [Linux Mint 19 Beta](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3581) based on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes).

I have an Intel Kaby Lake CPU: Intel© Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz ([Ark Intel](https://ark.intel.com/products/97185/Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz)).

I am curious as to what advantages / disadvantages an installed `intel-microcode` package has, if I regularly update my UEFI/BIOS; the latest update was on 13 Jun 2018.

I also regularly check for vulnerabilities with the help of [`spectre-meltdown-checker` from GitHub](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker).

Its output is the same as with or without `intel-microcode` installed (I rebooted after de-/installation before each check):

[image: spectre-meltdown-checker]

So, I suppose from the security standpoint I am covered, at the time of writing at least.

What I am unsure of, are other aspects, like **performance** or **stability** with or without the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Unless you have an uncommon reason, yes, you should have it installed.

## Long answer

The public `intel-microcode` distribution package is very low-risk, and after the issues with the first round of Spectre fixes, Intel has been even more conservative at pushing fixes to that distribution.

That means it is a good second-layer of safety to have it installed and up-to-date, in case your UEFI/BIOS starts getting outdated for whatever reason.

It is  fact that it *will* become relevant sooner or later when your system vendor starts getting sloppy at updating the firmware because your system is not being sold anymore, etc.